# Taking files off a docker container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to pull files off a docker container onto the local host?

I want to take certain directories off the docker containers I have worked on and move them to the local host on a daily basis.

Is this possible and how can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, simply use the `docker cp` command.

An example from the official CLI [documentation](http://docs.docker.io/reference/commandline/cli/) :

`sudo docker cp <container-id>:/etc/hosts .`

Answer (score 1):

May I ask what's the reason you want to copy these files out of the container? If it's a one off thing then you're better off copying them as @abronan suggested, but if these directories are something that you'll be copying out and copying back into another container or the same container next time, you might want to [look at volumes](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/) that enable you to have persistent data in your container as well as between containers

Comment: I am looking to creating a back up solution for the data in our containers, I want to create an incremental solution and am now looking at using rdiff to push data off the containers and onto a central back up server that I have created

Comment: I think it's generally better to keep your Data outside the containers  and use volumes for your solution, as containers have a disposable feel to them IMHO

Comment: Added to what Reza mentioned, you might be able to use Dockerfiles to download backups onto new images.  It depends on how you want to implement your restore feature.